# Application size not displayed under Add/Remove programs screen of the Windows

Tags: install4j

I have created .exe application with the help of **Install4j**. After successful installation of this application, the total size occupied by this application is not displayed under **Add/Remove programs** screen of the Windows.

How can I add total size of this application under **Add/Remove programs** with the help of **Install4j**?

[image]
Even Install4j also does not showing any size under **Add/Remove Program**

[image]

Comment: Windows calculates this automatically, there is no API to influence this. Are your files in a different directory than the installation directory?

Comment: Many Thanks Ingo. We have kept all files in single installation directory. But  still windows is not showing total size occupied by this application.

Comment: What is the difference between the actual size and the displayed size?

Comment: Actually application not showing any value under Size Column, Please refer attached screenshot in question.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to influence this value, it's not set by the program but Windows determines it by itself. What do you see for the install4j installation itself?